# How can I manually implement anti-aliasing with canvas?

Tags: javascript, math, rendering, antialiasing

I wrote a renderer of sorts that can create Signed Distance Fields in Javascript / Canvas

https://jsfiddle.net/MisterSirCode/zrbx8493/273/

It works well, but the SDFs it renders, while accurate, are rough and pixelated

(Im calculating each pixel manually and applying the color data based on the X Y position / distance and then editing the image data of the canvas)

[image]

This is less than what I want to achieve. I want the rendered SDFs to have an anti-aliased appearance, but I've never made an algorithm to achieve it, and I've found little online that could help me.

What I want to know is, how can I correctly alias the corners and edges of my SDFs to give them a smoother appearance from far away.

This is the main function I draw my SDFs onto the image data with: (The full source code is in the above link)

```js
draw() {
    let image = this.ctx.createImageData(this.image);
        let ivec = new Vector(image.width, image.height);
        for (var y = 0; y < image.height; ++y) {
            for (var x = 0; x < image.width; ++x) {
                let sphereOne = SDF.sphere(new Vector(ivec.x / 2, ivec.y / 2), 25)(new Vector(x, y, 1));
                let sphereTwo = SDF.sphere(new Vector(ivec.x / 4, ivec.y / 4), 15)(new Vector(x, y, 1));
                let dist = SDF.smoothAdd(sphereOne, sphereTwo, 35);
        let pos = (y * image.width + x) * 4;
                if (dist < 0) {
                    image.data[pos++] = x / image.width * 255;
                    image.data[pos++] = y / image.height * 255;
                    image.data[pos++] = (image.width - x) / image.width * 255;
                    image.data[pos] = 255;
                } else {
                    let bc = this.scene.backColor;
                    image.data[pos++] = bc[0] * 255;
                    image.data[pos++] = bc[1] * 255;
                    image.data[pos++] = bc[2] * 255;
                    image.data[pos] = bc[3] * 255;
                }
            }
        }
    this.ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend multi-sampling. Pick a number of positions within each pixel square, and compute the colour for each of them, then average the results.

There are a lot of minor knobs you can tweak. How many samples. Whether to arrange then in random positions or a regular grid. Whether to distribute them uniformly in a square, or in a circle, or whether to concentrate them closer to the center. Try whatever is easiest, then compare against alternatives if you're not happy with the result. The averaging operation can also be tuned to some degree, and ideally should be performed in some linear color space, even if the resulting image might be interpreted as [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) instead.

Personally I'd go with 9 regularly arranged sub-pixels for starters. Something like this (untested):

```js
const subpixels = [
  {x: -1/3, y: -1/3}, {x: 0, y: -1/3}, {x: 1/3, y: -1/3},
  {x: -1/3, y:    0}, {x: 0, y:    0}, {x: 1/3, y:    0},
  {x: -1/3, y:  1/3}, {x: 0, y:  1/3}, {x: 1/3, y:  1/3},
];
let pos = 0;
for (let yi = 0; yi < image.height; ++yi) {
  for (let xi = 0; xi < image.width; ++xi) {
    // We collect values from each sample in this:
    const accumulator = {r:0, g:0, b:0, a:0};
    for (subpixel of subpixels) {
      // Sub-pixel sample position is a combination of integer
       // position (xi, yi) and the specific subpixel offset.
      const x = xi + subpixel.x;
      const y = yi + subpixel.y;
      const sample = color_at(x, y);  // Computes dist, returns color.
      accumulator.r += sample.r;
      accumulator.g += sample.g;
      accumulator.b += sample.b;
      accumulator.a += sample.a;
    }
    // Turn sum of samples into [0-255] pixel value.
    // TODO: Perform gamma correction to transform linear to sRGB?
    const scale = 255 / subpixel.length;
    image.data[pos++] = accumulator.r * scale;
    image.data[pos++] = accumulator.g * scale;
    image.data[pos++] = accumulator.b * scale;
    image.data[pos++] = accumulator.a * scale;
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but Im more looking for a technique of HOW to do it. Ive never written kernel shaders, nor do I understand how to write an antialiaser. This is made even more difficult with the fact that I wrote this in javascript, and I dont "render" using traditional techniques. If I could find some kind of psuedocode for a basic antialiaser, I could most likely transpile it to my canvas renderer.

Comment: I've included a bit of code for illustration.

Comment: thankyou, Ill attempt to implement something like this into my code. I appreciate the help